# Log Ruby output in plain text without ANSI escape sequences

Tags: ruby, logging, ansi-escape

I'm redirecting my (non-Rails) ActiveRecord SQL logging to a text file with the following in my `spec_helper`:

```
logfile = File.expand_path('log/test.log')
FileUtils.mkdir_p File.dirname(logfile)
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(logfile) if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
```

This works great, except that the log file is full of ANSI color escapes. I suppose this is a feature if you're viewing it in a terminal, but it's extremely annoying when viewing the file in an IDE/editor:

[image]

How can I construct a `Logger` that outputs plain text?

---

**ETA:** And no, in case you're wondering, the old `ActiveRecord::Base.colorize_logging` flag you'll find documented all over the Internet for earlier ActiveRecord versions no longer exists, presumably because it was assumed only Rails developers needed plain-text logs.

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/dyna
mic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing': undefined method `colorize_logging=' 
for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess (and don't shoot me if I've misinterpreted your question):

```
ActiveRecord::Base includes a variety of configuration options:
colorize_logging (true by default) specifies whether or not to use ANSI color codes when logging information from ActiveRecord.
```

More details in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/configuring.html

## update

For Rails 3.0 and its version of ActiveRecord, you need to set `Rails::LogSubscriber` or `config.colorize_logging` instead.  From [the 3.0 release notes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/58255b9d28289ad6be59cd27cd6e0f35412eb449/guides/source/3_0_release_notes.md):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.colorize_logging and 
config.active_record.colorize_logging are deprecated in favor of
Rails::LogSubscriber.colorize_logging or config.colorize_logging
```

Comment: As of current versions of Rails that's [gone](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-active-record) in favor of a [general Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) `colorize_logging` config option. Unfortunately, as noted in the question, I'm not using Rails, and ActiveRecord appears to be colorized by default.

Comment: Except that, as noted, I'm not using Rails.

Comment: Oh, right -- my error.  I haven't dug into the sources; but can you perhaps get a handle on the LogSubscriber that ActiveRecord is using?